# Combine mutually exclusive arguments in filter condition

Tags: pandas, filter

I have a large Pandas DataFrame with >100 columns and I would like to select all columns where the substring `einkst_l` appears in the column name.
In addition, I want to select the two columns `name` and `year`.

So far, I could only create two new data frames:

```
e = 'einkst_l'
df_1 = df.filter(like = e, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df_2 = df.filter(items = ['name', 'year'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I would like to select all the columns in one shot, but unfortunately 'like' and 'items' cannot be combined in one statement.
How can I select name + year + all columns containing the specified substring all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more fuzzy but you could just use regex match like.

```
df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('einkst_l|name|year')]]
```

Also, could use ^ or $ to make match exactly for name and year.

Answer (score 1):

Try without `filter` using `str` accessors:

Replace:

- `like` by `contains`
- `items` by `isin`

```
out = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('einkst_l')
                    | df.columns.isin(['name', 'year'])]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like a "nested filtering":

```
df.filter(like = e, axis=1).filter(items = ['name', 'jahr'], axis=1)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. It only keeps the index.